# How to have a White Line insider of your pubspec.yaml

Tags: dart, redoc

Hi i was wondering how to have whitelines in your pubspec.yamls description? Because when i use the ->. Syntax redocly doesn't match the whitelines

Comment: What do you mean by "whiteline"?

Comment: The result of \n\n